# Can I access a child's method when it is classified as a parent?

Tags: java, object, inheritance

For example, I have an arraylist of objects that are all the parent type, but I want to access the child methods for one of the elements. This is the code I have:

```
ArrayList<Employee> staff = new ArrayList<Employee>();

for (Employee emp : staff) {
    if (emp.getType().equalsIgnoreCase("Manager")) {
        //use a method from the manager class with emp
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Manager` is a class that extends `Employee`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to make a type assertion, using the cast construct. While we're on the topic, having stringly typed `getType()` methods seems like a design error. That should either be an enum, or you can get rid of it altogether. Assuming you have:

```
class Employee {}
class Manager extends Employee {}
```

then:

```
for (Employee emp : staff) {
   if (emp instanceof Manager) {
       Manager m = (Manager) emp;
       m.doManageryThings();
   }
}
```

The `(Manager) emp` part is a type assertion: It acts like `m = emp` (which ordinarily wouldn't be a legal statement, but it is with this cast. It's the same object, but, now assigned to a variable of the type you wanted). If `emp` is not referencing a Manager, that will throw a ClassCastException. Then you're free to invoke whatever you want on m.

Starting with java, uh.. 14? 15? You can shorten this:

```
if (emp instanceof Manager m) {
   // use m here
}
```